# Mootools, looping through CSS classes

Tags: html, css, mootools

I'm trying to create a "slideshow" with background images of a div element. I have the image as a background due to the responsive nature. All I'm trying to do is loop through varying class names with intervals, so that the background will change to an image set up in CSS under a different class name. Bit of a newb in terms of MooTools.

I know how to change the class, with:

```
$$('Image').set('class', 'Image2');
```

I could possibly add:

```
.fade('in');
```

to the end, but unsure of the fade out on the existing background; as it would probably be instant?

Any ideas would be appreciate,

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code with what you have already done.